# heptagon shape for Linear/Realtive Layout in android

Tags: android

```
             heptagon shape for Linear/Realtive Layout in android
             inside heptgone we insert login form
```

heptagon shape for Linear/Realtive Layout in android
                 inside heptgone we insert login form
             i.e login form contain LinearLAyout inside linearlayout cantain username ,
            password and login button